# excel: concatenate values from userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have this UserForm called `CompData` and it seems like this:

[image]

The main objective of this form is to update a cell in the CONSULTA sheet with this string `=">" & DATE(year, month, day)` (or variations) where the values of DATE and the correct math symbol come from the form.

In the "Inserir" (it's my insert button) I associated this code:

```
Private Sub Inserir_Click()

If Maior.Value = True Then

    Worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("K23") = "=" > " & DATE(CompData.Ano.Value, CompData.Mes.Value, CompData.Dia.Value)"

ElseIf Maior.Value = True Then

    Worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("K23") = "=" < " & DATE(CompData.Ano.Value, CompData.Mes.Value, CompData.Dia.Value)"

ElseIf MaiorIgual.Value = True Then

    Worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("K23") = "=" >= " & DATE(CompData.Ano.Value, CompData.Mes.Value, CompData.Dia.Value)"

ElseIf MenorIgual.Value = True Then

    Worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("K23") = "=" <= " & DATE(CompData.Ano.Value, CompData.Mes.Value, CompData.Dia.Value)"

End If
End Sub
```

Maior, Menor, MaiorIgual and MenorIgual are the names of my option buttons.

Anyway, when I run the code, it gives me:

> Run-time error 461:
>   Method or data member not found

And highlights this part:

```
Private Sub Inserir_Click()
```

I know that exists a `CONCATENATE` function, but I don't think it will work on my VBA  code.

I don't know if I'm concatenating it right, but I really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Do you want to set the formula of the cell as `=">"&DATE(2017,6,8)` ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I want to set the formula of the cell as this, but with the year, month and day that I write on my form.

Comment: What would be your end result? You have problems in string concatenation.

Comment: @ManishChristian yes, I guess the concatenation is my problem. The result that I want is to set the value of a cell with =">"&DATE(year,month,date).

Comment: should `= "=" <= "` be `= "=<= "`

Comment: Replace all `"` around `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` with `""`.

Comment: @ManishChristian I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: On the face of things, one of the referenced controls should not exist. The error message doesn't indicate anything wrong with your concatenations. I know this looks unlikely, but you did make a mistake in writing `Maior` twice and missing `Menor`, so why not have one more type? Does `Compdata` exit by that name?

Comment: @OP so far it looks like an XY problem. First of all, what uou will get in the destination cell is something like `>42893`, that is, the resulting date will show as a number. To understand the ultimate purpose, would you show a *concrete example* of what you want to **see** in the cell?

Comment: Also your `If` and first `ElseIf` conditions are same.

Comment: @Variatus Yes, you're right. I corrected that, thank you.

Comment: @ManishChristian Yes, you were right. Now everything was corrected and it's working, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the formula of `K23` to `=">"&DATE(2017,6,8)` then you would code:

```
Worksheets("CONSULTA").Range("K23").Formula = "="">""&DATE(" & CompData.Ano.Value & "," & CompData.Mes.Value & "," & CompData.Dia.Value & ")"
```

Note the double `""` where you want to include a `"` within a string.

Comment: It still doesn't work... I edited the question with the highlighted part.

Comment: So if you replace all your `Worksheets("CONSULTA")...` statements in your code with my answer - do you still get that error?

Comment: Yes, I did this in the first place.

Comment: Are the textboxes actually called `Dia`, `Mes` and `Ano` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's working perfectly, thank you! I don't know what happened, I re-opened the file and everything was fine.

Comment: ++ With what Robin suggested it has to work :D Reopening the file will never fix these kind of issues. @paulinhax

Comment: @SiddharthRout No, I mean... I tried Robin solution and I didn't know why was not working out, so I close everything and open again and everything was fine.

Comment: ah ok... :D @paulinhax